# View Page (DispForm.aspx) not associated properly for Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have a list with customized versions of NewForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx and DispForm.aspx.
The list has been up for more than a year and contains about 1700 rows.

Earlier I made a minor change to DispForm.aspx and it seems like the list lost it's association with DispForm.aspx as the default view page. Links from all views now point to "site/?ID=123" instead of "site/SubSite/List/DispForm.aspx?ID=123".

I've used Sharepoint Designer to re-apply the settings for which files are associated with actions but it doesn't seem to work.

The site is running on multiple servers and I suspect that changes might not apply until a service restart (this has been the case for some other changes in the past), but hopefully someone here has some ideas.

Unfortunately, I have only remote access through SPD and no privileges outside the specific site.

Update: It seems my google-fu was weak earlier but I believe I found a possible solution
 [here](http://sharepointworks.blogspot.com/2009/05/repairing-supporting-files-sharepoint.html).

Comment: @Toft: If you find a solution please add it as an answer to this question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me: http://moblog.bradleyit.com/2008/10/broken-sharepoint-list-forms.html

Quick summary: Create a new GUID for the ListFormWebPart

```
<WebPartPages:ListFormWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{NEW_GUID}" >
```

This GUID is also used in the -tag inside the ListFormWebPart:

```
<ID>g_NEW_GUID</ID>
```